# c# slice a string index of specific character

Tags: c#, string

I want to slice that string 
`conStr = "server='MyServer';DataBase='MySQL';username='myAdmin';password='myPass';"`

`indexOf(;)`

and parse the values into an `object{string server, string DataBase,etc}`
how should i do that?

Comment: In this specific case you should use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder as @Rango wrote. But in general just use string.Split(';') to split the string in tokens

Answer (score 2):

You can use Split function to split your string into tokens

```
string phrase = "server='MyServer';DataBase='MySQL';username='myAdmin';password='myPass';";
string[] words = phrase.Split(';');
```